# Разделить колонку в DataFrame по определенным словам

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

есть Excel файл с данными. В одной колонке объединено много значений и их нужно разделить на несколько колонок.
Строки не всегда одинаковые, т.е. в любой строке может не быть какой-то части.
Вот примеры строк:

```
Производитель " BP EUROPA SE" тов. знак "НЕИЗВЕСТНА", марка BRAYCOTE 601EF кол-во=2  
Производитель " ITW PRO BRANDS " тов. знак "LPS" кол-во=105  
Производитель "77 B.V." тов. знак "77" марка "77"  
Производитель "ARMITE LABORATORIES INC" тов. знак "ARMITE" марка ARMITE LF-AS 328 артикул LF-AS 328 кол-во=5
```

Разделить нужно по словам "Производитель", "тов. знак", "марка", "артикул", "кол-во" по разным колонкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С обычной строкой мне удалось это сделать с помощью

```
new_value = re.split(r'Производитель|тов. знак|марка|модель|кол-во=',str)
```

А вот с DataFrame не получается.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Комментарии в коде

```
txt = """Производитель " BP EUROPA SE" тов. знак "НЕИЗВЕСТНА", марка BRAYCOTE 601EF кол-во=2
Производитель " ITW PRO BRANDS " тов. знак "LPS" кол-во=105
Производитель "77 B.V." тов. знак "77" марка "77"
Производитель "ARMITE LABORATORIES INC" тов. знак "ARMITE" марка ARMITE LF-AS 328 артикул LF-AS 328 кол-во=5"""
df = pd.DataFrame({'Текст': txt.split('\n')})

stopwords = 'Производитель|тов\. знак|марка|модель|артикул|кол-во=|$'  # перечень слов - ограничителей
pat = '|'.join(fr'{word}(?P<{"".join(x for x in word.title() if x.isalpha())}>.+?)(?={stopwords})' for word in stopwords.split('|')[:-1])  # формируем паттерн для извлечения фрагментов в виде именованных групп захвата
df = pd.concat([df, df['Текст'].str.extractall(pat).groupby(level=0).first().apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(' ",'))], axis=1)  # извлекаем нужные фрагменты, чистим от побочных символов и склеиваем результат с исходным фреймом
print(df)
```

```
                                                                                                          Текст            Производитель     ТовЗнак             Марка Модель    Артикул КолВо
0                           Производитель " BP EUROPA SE" тов. знак "НЕИЗВЕСТНА", марка BRAYCOTE 601EF кол-во=2             BP EUROPA SE  НЕИЗВЕСТНА    BRAYCOTE 601EF   None       None     2
1                                                   Производитель " ITW PRO BRANDS " тов. знак "LPS" кол-во=105           ITW PRO BRANDS         LPS              None   None       None   105
2                                                             Производитель "77 B.V." тов. знак "77" марка "77"                  77 B.V.          77                77   None       None  None
3  Производитель "ARMITE LABORATORIES INC" тов. знак "ARMITE" марка ARMITE LF-AS 328 артикул LF-AS 328 кол-во=5  ARMITE LABORATORIES INC      ARMITE  ARMITE LF-AS 328   None  LF-AS 328     5
```

Comment: Очень круто )  Мне даже думать было больно над решением, а вы это сделали ))

Comment: @Алексей Р Это просто магия!!! Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ!!!